# angularjs validation error for input field

Tags: angularjs

In the edit operation the value of the input box is filled by ng-model. But even though the value is present the validation shows red for input box as it needs a value to be typed.How to overcome this issue

```
<div class="row row-no-padding" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : schoolform.summary.$invalid || schoolform.summary.$pristine }">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 vz_input">
         <input  class="form-control" id="summary" name="summary" type="text" value="" placeholder="Summary" ng-model="project.summary" data-fv-field="summary" required jira-type="input" data-type="str">
    </div>        
</div>
```

Comment: Any reason you are putting `schoolform.summary.$pristine` as one of the css condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you should use `&&` instead of `||`. So it will be when the input is invalid and dirty:

```
<div class="row row-no-padding" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : schoolform.summary.$error.$required && schoolform.$submitted }">
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Is this a directive that is mean to be used on a loop or something? because then you should change the name or otherwise you will have a several inputs with the same name and i don't think this would be good

Comment: i meant to say if there is no value in the text box then does the validation holds good

Comment: I updated to use the $submitted property of the form so you can tell if the user already attempt top submitted the form. In my opinion this is the correct behaviour